# Why I am I getting errors when I try to use setOnCompletionListener with videoview?

Tags: android

I am trying to have my video proceed to the next activity after the video is finished. I have seen the other posts trying to do the same and I keep on getting errors all over the rest of my code when trying to implement them. My video played fine before trying to add this last part. Does anyone see any issues with my code? Thank you in advance.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_third);

        String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.leftwrist;

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Progressbar);
        mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        mProgressBar.setMax(100);

        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
        new myAsync().execute();
    }

    private class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        int duration = 0;
        int current = 0;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    duration = mVideoView.getDuration();
                }
            });

            do {
                current = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
                System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                        + current);
                try {
                    publishProgress((int) (current * 100 / duration));
                    if(mProgressBar.getProgress() >= 100){
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } while (mProgressBar.getProgress() <= 100);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            System.out.println(values[0]);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, FourthActivity.class);
```

in your case `this` refers to `OnCompletionListener` not activity.

Move following from AsyncTask to `onCreate`

```
  mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

for ex:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_third);

    String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.leftwrist;

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Progressbar);
    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    mProgressBar.setMax(100);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
   mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
    new myAsync().execute();
}
```

Comment: It worked after trying the edit you made. Thank you very much!!